# Make an asynchronous call from Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an af:outputText on my page.

Its value takes a long time to generate, so I don't want to generate when initially creating the page.

Instead, I'd like the page to make an asynchronous call back to the server once loaded, the return value will then populate the outputText.

What is the best way of achieving this in ADF?

Answer (score 4):

... or you use an af:poll component that checks the available status of the queried data. If the data is available, you disable the poll (ensure you PPR the af:poll component then)

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hare-brained idea that might work:

set your outputText's rendered property to false; This will cause its value expression not be evaluated while your page is being loaded.

On load of the page, fire a javascript AdfCustomEvent towards a server listener which will then toggle the rendered state and PPR the outputText.

A more complex but probably cleaner approach would be to look into ADS to lazy load the value somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Active Data Service (ADS) is a good fit for this. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31974/adv_ads.htm

Also Lucas Jellema has a great example of using ADS at http://technology.amis.nl/2011/10/19/adf-faces-handle-task-in-background-process-and-show-real-time-progress-indicator-for-asynchronous-job-using-server-push-in-adf/

Answer (score 0):

Use af:poll and set the partial trigger of af:OutputText to af:poll so that the OutputText will automatically get refreshed on the first poll.In the poll listener set the poll interval to -1 (disable it)